# Unreal Engine 4.25.3 crashes when it is compiled and clicked play

Tags: visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal

I am using VS CODE. I am studying Udemy lessons of UNREAL C++. at 45th lesson(making "Bull Cow Game"), I did as they say and tried to make unreal print "Hİ THERE" by using VS CODE. But UNREAL crashed. Error:

LoginId:418ab83d44c9d7a2f658178f337f9174 EpicAccountId:7aadca3dc68344419fd5e775294d71ad

Assertion failed: Terminal [File:C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame\Console\Cartridge.cpp] [Line: 12] [BullCowCartridge]: No Terminal found

UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_BullCowGame_7145!DispatchCheckVerify >() [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Misc\AssertionMacros.h:161] UE4Editor_BullCowGame_7145!UCartridge::BeginPlay() [C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame\Console\Cartridge.cpp:12] UE4Editor_BullCowGame_7145!UBullCowCartridge::BeginPlay() [C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame\BullCowCartridge.cpp:7] UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_Engine UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor_UnrealEd UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor kernel32 ntdll

How can I fix this?
I tried: adding in the terminal

```
cl BullCowCartridge.cpp/EHsc/Zi
```

Doing this gave this error:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame>cl BullCowCartridge.cpp/EHsc/Zi
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'BullCowCartridge.cpp/EHsc/Zi', object file assumed
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Zi.exe
BullCowCartridge.cpp/EHsc/Zi
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'BullCowCartridge.cpp\EHsc\Zi.obj'

C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame>

Press F5 in the Terminal gave this error:

> Executing task in folder BullCowGame: Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat BullCowGame Win64 Debug C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\BullCowGame.uproject -waitmutex <

Creating makefile for BullCowGame (no existing makefile)
ERROR: Targets cannot be built in the Debug configuration with this engine distribution.
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat BullCowGame Win64 Debug C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\BullCowGame.uproject -waitmutex" terminated with exit code: 6.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

What can I do?

Comment: Hey physicssolvesall, please check my answer, even after 3 years This could help the future SO community, Don't forget to sign as the Accepted Answer

Answer (score 0):

Assertion failed: Terminal [File:C:\UnrealBullCow\BullCowGame-starter-kit\Source\BullCowGame\Console\Cartridge.cpp] [Line: 12] [BullCowCartridge]: No Terminal found

That means you attached the component to an actor without a Terminal component or you removed the Terminal component already on the actor.

If you go into Console > Cartridge and change this on line 12

```
*GetName()
```

to

```
*GetOwner()->GetName()
```

The crash should tell you what actor is missing it.

One of the cows occurred as “terminal” in the "world outliner" tab, and one of the other cow has already had a Cartridge attached to it. After I deleted the terminal cow and delete the Cartridge from other cow, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Use the "Run and Debug" Button on the left side of the VSCode, and choose the “Launch [YourProject] DebugGame [YourProject]” from the drop-down. And hit the Run button again. That's it. After setting this, you're good to go with the "Run and Debug" button without touching any configuration.

#### Step 1

[image]

#### Step 2

[image]

### Shortcut

You can also use the shortcuts to Run with or without Debugging like this. Options can change by the OS type that you're using.

[image]